# How do I force a redirect with a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a parameter value which I have to URL encode. Therefore my understanding is that it must be sent as a query string on the end of the URL rather than part of the main URL. I have successfully tested this by directly pasting the URL into the browser.

I am trying to redirect to a URL of:

`Server/Application/Area/Controller/Action/?id=xyz`

But when I use

`return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { area = "Area", id = Url.Encode(uniqueId) });`

I am sent to

`Server/Application/Area/Controller/Action/xyz`

How do I stop this happening?

Comment: You cannot use `id` here because it's reserved in mvc routing just change `id` with something else then it will work fine or change name `id` with something else in default mvc route.

Comment: What is the problem? Both are binding the `id` parameter of your method to the value `xyz`

Comment: The problem is that xyz is url encoded. So it has to be part of the query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because of your default route is;

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Site", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

if you want to keep using this route, you should be have to change your id parameter in your url.

But if id parameter is omitted from the default route, your action redirected as you  expect.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Site", action = "Index"}
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove id from Default Route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

or change the name of your parameter from id to something else.

I hope this will help.